# Union type: cannot use the second optional type in a forloop

Tags: angular, typescript, union-types

I have an array which I want to loop thru, but I have trouble because the union type. My question is what have I missed from this following code, so the visual studio code does not see I have a second optional type for that particular array?

```
class Menu {
  // name of the menu
 name: string;
  // list of the ingredients in this menu
  // or a list of submenu with its ingredients
 list: string[] | Menu[];
 hasSubList?: boolean;
}

...
menu: Menu[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadMenu();
}
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.print();
}
loadMenu(): void {
  this.menu = [
   {
     name: "toast" 
     list: [
      "slide of bread",
     ],
   },
   {
     name: "Crumble eggs on taste",
     hasSubList: true;
     list: [
      {
        name: "Eggs",
        list: [
         {
           "Eggs",
           "pepper",
           "a pinch of salt",
          }
         ],
       },
       {
        name: "Toast",
        list: [
          "a slide of bread"
         ],
        },
       ],
   },
 ];
}

this print(): void {
  for(let i=0; i<this.menu.length;i++){
    let item = this.menu[i];
    console.log(item.name);
    for(let j=0; i<item.list.length; j++){
      let list = item.list[j];
      if(item.hasSubList) {
         // HERE
         // console intellsense says 
         // "property 'list' does not exist on type 'string | Menu'
         // "property 'list' does not exist on type 'string'
        for(let k=0; k< list.list.length; k++}(
          console.log(list.list[k]);
        }
      } else {
       console.log(list);
      }
}
```

Just to recap on the message on what the intellsense showed;

```
"property 'list' does not exist on type 'string | Menu'
"property 'list' does not exist on type 'string'
```

Why didn't it check for Menu? because 'list' exists as type 'Menu'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @jacobm the compiler has no way to know based on **hasSubList** what the actual type of the union type is.

You have to use a way to discriminate it that the compiler can understand. 1 Way to do this is to check the type of the item itself, and then you don't even need the **hasSubList** property at all.

e.g.

```
for(let i=0; i<this.menu.length;i++){
    let item = this.menu[i];

    for(let j=0; i<item.list.length; j++){
        let list = item.list[j];

        // typeof operator can help discriminate the union type
        if(typeof item !== 'string') {
            for(let k=0; k< list.list.length; k++}(
                console.log(list.list[k]);
            }
        } else {
            console.log(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's another example using for..of loops instead of for loops. This may be a stylistic preference, but I would recommend using them in cases where you aren't consuming the index of the loop as they are more concise and IMO are more readable.

```
for (let item of menu) {
    for (let list of item.list) {
        if(item !== 'string') {
            for(let childItem of list.list) {
                console.log(childItem);
            }
        } else {
            console.log(list);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `list[j]` has type `string | Menu`, the code that uses it has to be able to handle *either* strings or Menus, it can't handle just one or the other. I think you're relying on the knowledge that if `hasSubList` is true then `list` is always a list of menus. If that's what you mean, then you can cast `item` to a menu (`list as Menu`), though in general it's better to avoid casts like that because they limit how much the type checker can catch true mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The message is caused by Typescript can't tell which type are you going to use since you assign it as `string | Menu[]`. Use cast is one way to solve this issue.

```
for (let j = 0; i < item.list.length; j++) {
    if (item.hasSubList) {
      let list = item.list[j] as Menu; // use 'as'     
      for (let k = 0; k < list.list.length; k++) {
        console.log(list[k]);
      }
    } else {
      let list = item.list[j];  
      console.log(list);
    }
  }
```